# noisy pic after drawing big PNG file on cavnas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have problem with drawing this (1766 * 2880) PNG file on canvas.
But I don't have any problem with JPG format of that size or (1533 * 2500) size of PNG file.
I consider `devicePixelRatio` for scaling canvas, and ignoring the ratio makes no changes.

[image: noisy pic after drawing big PNG file on canvas]

```
var loadImage = function (url) {

    var ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1),
        image = new Image();

    image.onload = function () {
        var paper = '#paper-0',
            canvas = $(paper)[0],
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            img = this;

        var w = Math.ceil(img.width / ratio), h = Math.ceil(img.height / ratio);

        $(paper).css({ width: w + 'px', height: h + 'px' });

        canvas.width = w * ratio;
        canvas.height = h * ratio;

        ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
    }
    image.src = url;
}
```

Comment: The problem is with the image (png), it is either corrupted, or in a format unsupported by the browser. Use an image editor, open the image,then if not corrupted, copy and paste the image into a new image. Save that as a png using any of the standard png image options, then try and load the new on.

Comment: @Blindman67 , I saved that image in multiple sizes, and there is no problem with size smaller than (1533 * 2500). So the image is not corrupted.

Comment: Nope this problem is with your graphic card. I have this too sometimes, when requiring too much for it (not only in a browser). Not too much you can do apart from upgrading your device... Maybe you can try to disable hardware acceleration in your browser.

Comment: You could try and update the graphics card drivers if you have not done it for a while.